# Python timedelta time difference from the given varied time of every day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timedelta

I have the these two following pandas dataframe :

```
df1 = {'Date' : ['07-10-2019',
              '07-10-2019',
              '07-10-2019',
              '08-10-2019',
              '08-10-2019',
              '08-10-2019']}

df1 = {'Time' :['07-10-2019 10:47:00',
              '07-10-2019 10:52:00',
              '07-10-2019 10:59:00',
              '08-10-2019 10:47:00',
              '08-10-2019 10:52:00',
              '08-10-2019 10:59:00',
]}
```

and I am trying to create `d['Time Taken']` by using: 
`df1['Time Taken']=((pd.to_datetime(df1['Time'])-pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])).dt.total_seconds())/60` 
and clearly as expected, I am getting resultant `df1['Time Taken']` as:

```
df1 = {'Time Taken': [647.0,
                      652.0,
                      659.0,
                      647.0,
                      652.0,
                      659.0,
]}
```

However, I would like to see `df['Time Taken]` start with `NaN` or `0`. How should I write it this line code to make it look like:

```
df1 = {'Time Taken': [NaN,
                      5.0,
                      7.0,
                      NaN,
                      5.0,
                      7.0,
]}
```

Please, help me with this! Many thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what are those `NaN, 5.0, 7.0, .....` values? What do they represent?

Comment: Hi, they are time difference between the time mentioned in the row prior. `NaN` is because there's no row prior for that date to substract time from. `5.0`  is value substracted from `10:52:00`
 and `10:47:00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) with [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and divide `60`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date' : ['07-10-2019',
              '07-10-2019',
              '07-10-2019',
              '08-10-2019',
              '08-10-2019',
              '08-10-2019'], 
              'Time' :['07-10-2019 10:47:00',
              '07-10-2019 10:52:00',
              '07-10-2019 10:59:00',
              '08-10-2019 10:47:00',
              '08-10-2019 10:52:00',
              '08-10-2019 10:59:00',
]})

df1['Time']= pd.to_datetime(df1['Time'])


df1['Time Taken'] = df1.groupby('Date')['Time'].diff().dt.total_seconds() / 60
print(df1)
         Date                Time  Time Taken
0  07-10-2019 2019-07-10 10:47:00         NaN
1  07-10-2019 2019-07-10 10:52:00         5.0
2  07-10-2019 2019-07-10 10:59:00         7.0
3  08-10-2019 2019-08-10 10:47:00         NaN
4  08-10-2019 2019-08-10 10:52:00         5.0
5  08-10-2019 2019-08-10 10:59:00         7.0
```

Comment: oh yes. `groupby`. Thank you so much, really appreciate it!